# Data Base error - requires upgrade to continue "This Database file is not compatible with the current instance of SQL Sever..."

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i have to do a Project for school a site in aspx
and i have to do Database to login users and register
but when i try to click on the Database it says an error:
http://prntscr.com/fjfrbp
i don't know what i can do?

This is my registration.aspx.cs code:

```
    if (Request.Form["submit"] != null)
{
    string fName = Request.Form["fName"];
    string lName = Request.Form["lName"];
    string Passwod = Request.Form["Passwod"];
    string email = Request.Form["email"];
    string add = Request.Form["add"];

    string RegStatus;

    if ((fName == "") || (lName == "") || (Passwod == "") || (email == "") || (add == ""))
    {
        RegStatus = ("missing data or wrong data");
    }
    else
    {
        string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + "[Users]";
        selectQuery += " WHERE ";
        selectQuery += " email = '" + Request.Form["email"] + "'";

        if (MyAdoHelper.IsExist(selectQuery))
        {
            RegStatus = ("email does not exists");
        }
        else
        {
            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [Users] (fName,lName,Passwod, email,add) VALUES ('";
            insertQuery += fName + "', '" + lName +"','" + Passwod + "', '" + email + "','" + add +"')";
            Response.Write(insertQuery);
            MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(insertQuery);
            RegStatus = ("Registeration was successful "); 
        }
    }

    Response.Write(RegStatus);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: either you accessing the wrong the database or may require upgrading... how did your development go?

Comment: i had no problems in development
but when i tried to enter the database i got that error.

Comment: and in the dev enviroment you are using the same database and credentials?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exaclty
but i used Visual Studio 2015 for the whole Project including code and Database

Comment: okay... so is it the same database you are accessing and used for development?

Comment: Yes, i overcame the error in the Thread by making a new Database
but i still can't connect to it, i don't know what im doing wrong